# dojo iconClass toggle

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a of series images in my css file with different class names. I then have external js with a function with a case statement that detects whatever state we are in and then I want to

```
dojo.addClass(this.id + "IDName", "iconName")
```

but, this does not change my default iconClass. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You must first remove the existing icon class and then add the new one.

Comment: Adding something like this? `registry.byId(this.id+"IDName").attr("iconClass","iconClassName");` ?

Comment: Try `dojo.removeClass(this.id + "IDName", "oldIconName"); dojo.addClasS(this.id + "IDName", "newIconName");`

Answer (score 0):

I used `registry.byId(this.id + "IDName").set("iconClass",functionName());`